# How can I make the caption responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image with an caption on the left-middle. The caption should be always at the left-middle or anywhere on the left side of the image and it's size should be vary with browser size simultaneously.
The problem is that when I resize the window than size of the caption won't change and It's position is also not fixed w.r.t the image.

```css
.page-overview{
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .overview-content img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .caption{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        left: 18px;
        font-size: 80%;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .caption span{
        display: block;
        margin: 8px 0;
        padding: 10px 17px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #00000033;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test YOU</title>
  
</head>
<body>

    <!--Here can have other content too-->
    <div class="page-overview">
        <div class="overview-content"><a href="#"><img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/481/481903.png" alt="Delilious & Yum" height="auto"></a>
            <div class="caption">
                <span>Test your best here</span>
                <span>It's Yum </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you trying to center it? Your code currently sets an absolute position of 20% top and 18px left.

Comment: ohh my bad... I just wanted to make it float at anywhere on left side,

Comment: `overview-content` should be `position:relative`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` and use relative instead. `absolute` will not account for browser shrinkage, it will just still stay in the specified area.

```css
.page-overview {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overview-content img {
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto 0;
  top: 20%;
  left: 18px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
}

.caption span {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00000033;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>test YOU</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!--Here can have other content too-->
  <div class="page-overview">
    <div class="overview-content">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/481/481903.png" alt="Delilious & Yum" height="auto"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <span>Test your best here</span>
        <span>It's Yum </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Kusan2030 No problem. I also made you a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/myu7z4v9/) that uses flex to align the `caption` inline with the image, assuming that is what you were trying to accomplish with `absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing is to wrap a `position:absolute` divs with a `position:relative` div, so the absolute div will be relative that that parent.
Besides that, I used flexbox to center the content.
That is assuming you want the caption ON the image...

```css
.page-overview{
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .overview-content img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .caption{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 80%;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .caption span{
        display: block;
        margin: 8px 0;
        padding: 10px 17px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #00000033;
    }
    
    .image-wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test YOU</title>
  
</head>
<body>

    <!--Here can have other content too-->
    <div class="page-overview">
        <div class="overview-content">
          <div class="image-wrapper">
            <a href="#">
          
              <img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/481/481903.png" alt="Delilious & Yum" height="auto"/>
            </a>
              <div class="caption">
                  <span>Test your best here</span>
                  <span>It's Yum </span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```